# how to fix Route [projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask] not defined in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing application using laravel 5.2 and I have form.blade.php file in my subtasks folder in view folder.
subtasks/form.blade.php

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask')}}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="text" name="task_name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('task_name') ?: '' }}">
                @if ($errors->has('task_name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('task_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create Task</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
```

My controller is this

```
public function store(Request $request,$projectId,$taskId)
    {
        $subtask = new Subtask;
        $subtask->subtask_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $subtask->task_id = $taskId;
        $subtask->project_id = $projectId;

        $subtask->save();
        //
    }
```

my routes are here

```
Route::get('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask', function ($projectId, $taskId) {

    return view('subtasks/form',['projectId'=>$projectId,'taskId'=>$taskId]);
});

Route::post('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask','SubtasksController@store');
```

but I got this error messages

```
Route [projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask] not defined.
```

how can fix this?

Comment: The `route` command is expecting the name of the route, which you have not specified. More information can be found at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes

Comment: can you explain in code here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: name your route:

```
Route::post('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask','SubtasksController@store')
->name('subtask_route);
```

and your form would use this. Remember to pass in the correct projectId and taskId

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('subtask_route', ['projectId'=> $projectId, 'taskId'=>$taskId])}}">
```

Or create the url yourself:

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="/projects/{{$projectId}}/task/{{$taskId}}/subtask">
```

Comment: what did you mean **subtask_route**

Comment: As you see in the first section of code, I've named the route `subtask_route`. You can name it whatever you like, as long as the name on the route and the name you use for the route command are the same.

Comment: actually I have two routes regarding with this subtask form Route::get is show My form and Route::post is post My input data. really Route::post is not working...

Comment: Ah, got it. Let me edit the code with the correct route, but the rest will be the same.